# How to parallelize or make faster python script

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have a code where text file manipulation is taking place. Although text files are very large and with my current code as i calculated it needs 30 days to finish.

If multiprocessing is he only way i have a server with 40 cores.

Cell_line_final2.bed:

```
chr1    778704  778912  MSPC_Peak_37509  8.43   cell_line   GM12878  CTCF   ENCSR000AKB CNhs12333   132
chr1    778704  778912  MSPC_Peak_37509  8.43   cell_line   GM12878  CTCF   ENCSR000AKB CNhs12331   132
chr1    778704  778912  MSPC_Peak_37509  8.43   cell_line   GM12878  CTCF   ENCSR000AKB CNhs12332   132
chr1    869773  870132  MSPC_Peak_37508  74.0   cell_line   GM12878  CTCF   ENCSR000AKB CNhs12333   132
...
...
```

tf_TPM2.bed:

```
CNhs12333   2228319     4.41    CTCF
CNhs12331   6419919     0.0     HES2
CNhs12332   6579994     0.78    ZBTB48
CNhs12333   8817465     0.0     RERE
...
...
```

The desired output is to add a column in "Cell_line_final2.bed" where 1st and 4th column of "tf_TPM2.bed" match 10th and 8th column of "Cell_line_final2.bed" simultaneously .

```
chr1    778704  778912  MSPC_Peak_37509  8.43   cell_line   GM12878  CTCF   ENCSR000AKB CNhs12333   132   4.41
chr1    778704  778912  MSPC_Peak_37509  8.43   cell_line   GM12878  HES2   ENCSR000AKB CNhs12331   132   0.0
chr1    778704  778912  MSPC_Peak_37509  8.43   cell_line   GM12878  CTCF   ENCSR000AKB CNhs12332   132   0.78
chr1    869773  870132  MSPC_Peak_37508  74.0   cell_line   GM12878  RERE   ENCSR000AKB CNhs12333   132   0.0
...
...
```

My code so far:

```
def read_file(file):
    with open(file) as f:
        current = []
        for line in f: # read rest of lines
            current.append([x for x in line.split()])
    return(current)


inputfile = "/home/lside/Desktop/database_files/Cell_line_final2.bed" # 2.7GB text file
outpufile = "/home/lside/Desktop/database_files/Cell_line_final3.bed"

file_in = read_file("/home/lside/Desktop/tf_TPM2.csv") # 22.5MB text file
new_line = ""
with open(inputfile, 'r') as infile:
    with open(outpufile, 'w') as outfile:
        for line in infile:
            line = line.split("\t")
            for j in file_in:
                if j[0] == line[9] and j[3] == line[7]:
                    new_line = new_line + '{0}\t{1}\t{2}\t{3}\t{4}\t{5}\t{6}\t{7}\t{8}\t{9}\t{10}\t{11}\n'.format(line[0], line[1], line[2],line[3], line[4], line[5],line[6], line[7], line[8], line[9], line[10].rstrip(), j[2])
                    continue
        outfile.write(new_line)
```

Comment: `new_line = new_line + '{0}...'` Concatenation of large strings is _very_ slow.

Comment: Start by profiling your code to determine where the bottle neck is. If it is during any computations, then you should first find an alternative solution without multiprocessing. Only once you've optimized the algorithm should you start looking at multiprocessing.

Comment: @jtwilson Note: the code concatenates all lines into a single string and writes that.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice thank you i just noticed that

Comment: @Code-Apprentice the bottle neck is ```for j in file_in: ..... ``` but i cant optimize that

Comment: @Dimitris no, that is definitely not going to take 30 days. Simply iterating, even over a very large file, will be very fast. *That isn't your bottleneck*.

Comment: As an aside, `[x for x in line.split()]` is an overly verbose and redundant way of writing `line.split()`

Comment: I would also make so that `read_file` returns only two items per line, instead of the whole line. You only use elements `0` and `3` for the comparison anyway.

Comment: it seems you have data separated by tab - so it is very similar to csv format and you could use module `csv` to read and write it. Or maybe you could use [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) for this. pandas uses modules created in C/C++ so it may works faster. Probably `pandas` can use [Apahce Sparks](https://spark.apache.org/) to split problem on many servers.

Comment: Not related to your problem, but you can combine your `with` statements onto one line and save yourself an indent. `with open(inputfile, 'r') as infile, open(outpufile, 'w') as outfile:`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with comments saying that this should not take 30 days to run so the bottleneck should be somewhere else. Probably the biggest offender is the huge string that you are building, instead of just dumping each line to file at every iteration (^).

#### NOTE

(^) *The biggest offender is more likely to have been the `continue` statement in the inner loop, as that will always force the code to compare the current line with all the elements in the lookup file, rather than stop at the first match. Replacing that with a `break` should be the way to go.*

Here what I would do and see how fast this performs:

```
def read_file(filename):
    with open(filename) as f:
        current = []
        for line in f: # read rest of lines
            e0, e2, e3 = line.split()[0], line.split()[2], line.split()[3]
            current.append((e0, e2, e3))  # you only use these three elements
    return current


inputfile = "/home/lside/Desktop/database_files/Cell_line_final2.bed" # 2.7GB text file
outpufile = "/home/lside/Desktop/database_files/Cell_line_final3.bed"

file_in = read_file("/home/lside/Desktop/tf_TPM2.csv") # 22.5MB text file

with open(inputfile, 'r') as infile:
    with open(outpufile, 'w') as outfile:
        for line in infile:
            line = line.split("\t")
            for e0, e2, e3 in file_in:
                if e0 == line[9] and e3 == line[7]:
                    new_line = '{0}\t{1}\n'.format(line.rstrip(), e2)  # just append the column to the entire line
                    outfile.write(new_line)  # dump to file, don't linger around with an ever-growing string
                    break
```

## Lookup table

If we want to go further, we can make a lookup table from the `file_in`. The idea is that, instead of having to loop through every element extracted from `file_in`, we prepare a dictionary where the key is prepared from `j[0],j[3]` - which are the fields you compare - and the value is `j[2]`. This way, the lookup is going to be practically instantaneous, no loop necessary anymore.

The modified code to use this logic looks like this:

```
def make_lookup_table(filename):
    lookup = {}
    with open(filename) as f:
        for line in f: # read rest of lines
            e0, e2, e3 = line.split()[0], line.split()[2], line.split()[3]
            lookup[(e0, e3)] = e2  # use (e0,e3) as key, and e2 as value
    return lookup


inputfile = "/home/lside/Desktop/database_files/Cell_line_final2.bed" # 2.7GB text file
outpufile = "/home/lside/Desktop/database_files/Cell_line_final3.bed"

lookup = make_lookup_table("/home/lside/Desktop/tf_TPM2.csv") # 22.5MB text file

with open(inputfile, 'r') as infile:
    with open(outpufile, 'w') as outfile:
        for line in infile:
            line = line.split("\t")
            value = lookup[(line[9],line[7])]
            new_line = '{0}\t{1}\n'.format(line.rstrip(), value)  # just append the column to the entire line
            outfile.write(new_line)  # dump to file, don't linger around with an ever-growing string
```

Comment: Unforgettably it does ```6 iteration/sec``` and mine made ```11 iteration/sec``` measured with tqdm. The total iteration are 28579620 so even with 11 iteration ```28579620/11=2598147sec = 30days```  :(

Comment: I made a version with a lookup table, which will cut down the inner loop over `in_file`. However, I don't think that it should run *that* slow.

Comment: Lookup table works very fast! It does 165000 it/sec. @sal thank you very much for the solution! It finished in 1min.... Thank's again!
If possible can you explain a bit what a Lookup table does?

Comment: That's awesome! Glad to help! Yes, let me add a bit more on the lookup table in the answer above. Very happy it helped.

Comment: Can you try the first version again? I think I should have used `break` instead of `continue` in the loop. I updated the answer with this change, and would be curious to know if that is still *that* slow.

Comment: Side note: Since tuples are immutable and hashable you can use `(e0, e3)` as dict keys instead of concatenating the string representations.

Comment: @warownia1 I didn't know that! Thanks for sharing. I learned something new. I will update my answer to include this suggestion.

Comment: Yes break is the way to go! Even more faster approach! Thanks for the look up comments

Comment: I guess that's what the *real* issue with your code was to start with. :-)

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to suggest quite unconventional solution which makes use of SQL.
Fist, create two tables which will store your data and line number.

```py
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')  # you may consider file if short on RAM
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute('CREATE TABLE table1 (line INT, col1, col4);')
c.execute('CREATE TABLE table2 (line INT, col8, col10);')
conn.execute()
```

Then, read lines from your files and write rows to the database

```py
for index, line in enumerate(open('tf_TPM2.csv')):
    tokens = line.split()
    c.execute('INSERT INTO table1 VALUES (?, ?, ?);', (index, tokens[0], tokens[3])
conn.commit()
for index, lint in enumerate(open('Cell_line_final2.bed')):
    tokens = line.split()
    c.execute('INSERT INTO table2 VALUES (?, ?, ?);', (index, tokens[7], tokens[9])
conn.commit()
```

Finally, issue the query, which checks which rows have matching values and fetch the line number.

```
query = c.execute(
    'SELECT table2.line, table1.line '
    'FROM table1, table2 '
    'WHERE table1.col1 == table2.col10 AND table1.col4 == table2.col8 '
    'ORDER BY table2.line;'
)
while True:
    result = query.fetchone()
    if result is None: break
    # print result to file
```

The result will contain the line numbers, but you can put and query other columns as well.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another example using a `set` for lookup:

```
def main():
    f = Filter(TPM_fn='tf_TPM2.bed', final_fn='Cell_line_final2.bed',
               save_fn='Cell_line_final3.bed')

class Filter:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.args = kwargs
        self.read_TPM()
        with open(self.args['save_fn'], 'w') as outfile:
            with open(self.args['final_fn'], 'r') as infile:
                self.read_infile(infile, outfile)


    def read_infile(self, infile, outfile):
        for line in infile:
            fields = line.split()
            key = fields[9]+fields[7]
            if key in self.tpm:
                outfile.write(line)
        return 


    def read_TPM(self):
        fn = self.args['TPM_fn']
        tpm = set()
        with open(fn) as f:
            for line in f:
                fields = line.split()
                if len(fields) != 4:
                    continue 
                key = fields[0]+fields[3]
                tpm.add(key)
        self.tpm = tpm

main()
```